# jenkins pipeline fails without some explanatory exception

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ami

I have a pipeline where among other parameters like machine name, client it is supposed to get latest ami from aws for that branch for example and then put it the clien.json which terraform would use to create the machine but als I want to enable the user to be able to provide a value for the parameter and when there is no value for that parameter to have the value picked from latest ami in develop for example:

#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {
agent { label 'new' }

```
parameters {

    string(name: 'AMI_ID', defaultValue: '', description: '[Mandatory]')

}


stages {


    stage('Retrieve latest AMI.') {
        when {
            expression { ${AMI_ID} == '' }
        }
        steps {
            script {
               AMI_ID = sh(script: "aws ec2 describe-images --region region1 --owners 123456 --filters \"Name=tag:type,Values=develop\" --query 'sort_by(Images, &CreationDate)[-1].ImageId'  | jq -r '.'", returnStdout: true).trim()
                echo "AMI retrieved: " + $ { AMI_ID }

            }
        }
    }
    stage("Updating client data") {
        environment {
            TERRAHELP_KEY = credentials('some-key')
        }
        steps {

            dir("data/clients/") {


                clientJson = readJSON file: "${CLIENT}.json"

                clientJson.put("client_ec2_eda_ami_id", ${ AMI_ID })

                writeJSON file: "${CLIENT}.json", json: clientJson, pretty: 4

                echo "Following  data will be applied:"
                sh "cat ${CLIENT}.json"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is the `CLIENT` variable defined anywhere?

Comment: Yes it is passed as parameter in the pipeline alongside the AMI_ID param but I trimmed to much the script for confidentiality.

The pipeline breaks when it reaches the line: 
 clientJson.put("client_ec2_eda_ami_id", ${ AMI_ID })

Comment: Would removing the extra whitespace make any difference, i.e., instead of `${ AMI_ID }` use `${AMI_ID}`?

Comment: tried that too:           clientJson.put("client_ec2_eda_ami_id", ${AMI_ID})

same result

Comment: 1. What exactly is the `client.json`? It should likely be replaced by passing the JP param directly as a TF var. 2. Your first stage should be replaced with `data` in your Terraform config. Also I think you may have scoping issues for that var, and that syntax for it in the second stage may be invalid.

Comment: yea scoping issues was one of the problems the second was making groovy read a shell variable and I started getting like: 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root cause was that I was passing a shell script variable to groovy where I say:

```
clientJson.put("client_ec2_eda_ami_id", ${ AMI_ID })
```

Instead I should have passed the AMI_ID to a groovy variable above and say like:

clientJson.put("client_ec2_eda_ami_id", currentAmi)

Peace of the code with the aws query dimmed:

```
    stage('Retrieve latest AMI.') {
        }
        steps {
            script {
                currentAmi = params.AMI_ID
                if (currentAmi.isEmpty())
                    currentAmi = sh(script: "aws ec2 query blah blah")
                        echo  "Ami retrieved is: ${currentAmi}"
            }
        }
    }

    stage("Updating client data") {
        environment {
            TERRAHELP_KEY = credentials('some-key')
        }
        steps {

            dir("data/clients/") {
                clientJson = readJSON file: "${CLIENT}.json"

                clientJson.put("client_ec2_eda_ami_id", currentAmi)

                writeJSON file: "${CLIENT}.json", json: clientJson, pretty: 4

                echo "Following  data will be applied:"
                sh "cat ${CLIENT}.json"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```